# Custom UITabBar in Monotouch

Tags: iphone, ios5, xamarin.ios, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I am trying to create a custom UITabBar. I have the regular UITabBarController working fine, but optimally, I wish to get it looking like this: [image: image of uitabbar]

What is the best way to approach this? I can't seem to find any useful examples in Monotouch.

Thanks

Comment: Got some examples in Objective-C ? Share them! :-) They are often very easy to either bind (as a static library) or port to C#. In both cases you get to learn a lot from it

Answer (score 1):

The way I figured to make a tab bar like that, is just a bunch of custom buttons that are arranged and programmed to look like a tab bar, but really they are just buttons. I was able to recreate the instagram tab bar in one of my apps and it looks fairly similar. That's the only way I could figure how to do this type of tab bar when I was teaching myself.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I figured this is what I'd have to do...Kind of build my own view to mimic the look and feel of a tabbar.

Answer (score 1):

There are some really good explanations around for how to do custom tab bars - especially on http://idevrecipes.com/2010/12/16/raised-center-tab-bar-button/ - source on https://github.com/boctor/idev-recipes/tree/master/RaisedCenterTabBar

I believe I have seen a github monotouch sample of this same code but I can't find it right now!