# How to create custom UITabBar

Tags: ios, uitabbar

I want to create custom `UITabBar` with custom `UITabBar` image and custom `UITabBarItem` selected image and unselected image.

Comment: Please give more detail.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you are looking into? You can customize this pretty heavily. Plus the code has a number of demos and examples for you to look at.

[Custom UITabBar in Monotouch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10218593/custom-uitabbar-in-monotouch)

[Change the image on UITabBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10127869/change-the-image-on-uitabbar)

Here is a good [EXTERNAL](http://www.rumex.it/2010/07/how-to-customise-the-tab-bar-uitabbar-in-an-iphone-application-part-1-of-2/) source for customization of the UI.

Answer (score 0):

you could take a look at mine as an example.

I did write an iOS 7+ compatible simple UITabBar+UITabBarController replacement that can support any number of tabs and that uses Auto Layout to build it's view hierarchy. Check out [NGTabBar](http://www.github.com/goles/ngtabbar).